# Enumerating list of applications installed using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I use the following code to enumerate applications installed in my system:

```
        ManagementObjectSearcher mos            = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product");
        ManagementObjectCollection collection   = mos.Get();
        List<string> appList = new List<string>();
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in collection)
        {
            try
            {
                string appName = mo["Name"].ToString();
                appList.Add(appName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

When I use this code in console or a WPF application, I get the exact list of apps. But when I use it in a windows service, I'm not getting the entire list. In my case its 1 application less. Is there a limitation to use this in Windows Service?

Comment: Have you tried to check what product you don't get? Maybe it's only installed for one user and the windows service is running under another user account?

Comment: My service is installed in LocalSystem and yes that app was installed for a particular user. But service should enumerate all right?